# Searching an Array of Strings from User Input in C

Tags: c

I've got this homework assignment where we get the user to enter the amount of lines of strings they desire, they then proceed to enter them which gets stored in a 2D Array (thus creating an array of strings). Then a switch case menu will be displayed which should

1. Search a character entered by the user, returns the amount of times the character occurred in the array
2. Search a word entered by the user, returns the amount of times the word occurred in the array
3. Have the user enter a specified word length and return the amount of times words of the specified length occur.

I have a couple problems with my code. The program runs without errors from the compiler. The `searchByCharacter` function works fine but the `searchByWord` only returns a value of 0 regardless of any word inputted and nothing happens after I input a number for the `searchByLength` function. The program freezes after I enter a length once I select the `searchByLength` function. I've been at this for a while and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LENGTH 80
#define MAX_LINES 10
#define WORD_LENGTH 20

void readText(char text[][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int n)
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter %d number of lines:\n", n);
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", text[i]);
    }
}

int searchByCharacter(char text[][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int n, char c)
{
    int i, charCount = 0, j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        j = 0;
        while(text[i][j] != '\0')
        {
            if(text[i][j] == c)
            {
                charCount++;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    return charCount;
}

int searchByWord(char text[][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int n, char * keyword)
{
    int i, wordCount = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int j = 0;
        int lengthOfWord = 0;
        char wordCheck[WORD_LENGTH];
        char * currentLine = text[i];
        while(currentLine[j] != '\0')
        {
            if (currentLine[j] == ' ' || currentLine[j] == '\n' || currentLine[j] == ',' || currentLine[j] == '.' ||
                currentLine[j] == ';')
            {
                wordCheck[lengthOfWord] = '\0';
                int matchingWord = strcmp(wordCheck, keyword);
                if(matchingWord == 0)
                {
                    wordCount++;
                }
                lengthOfWord = 0;
                j++;
                continue;
            }
            wordCheck[lengthOfWord] = currentLine[n];
            lengthOfWord++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    return wordCount;
}

int searchByLength(char text[][MAX_LINE_LENGTH], int n, int wordLen)
{
    int i, lengthCount = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int lengthOfWord = 0;
        int j = 0;
        char * currentLine2  = text[i];

        while(currentLine2[j] != '\0')
        {
            if (currentLine2[j] == ' ' || currentLine2[j] == '\n' || currentLine2[j] == ',' || currentLine2[j] == '.' ||
                currentLine2[j] == ';')
            {
                    if(lengthOfWord == wordLen)
                    {
                        lengthCount++;
                    }

                    lengthOfWord = 0;
                    n++;
                    continue;
            }
            lengthOfWord++;
            n++;
        }
    }
    return lengthCount;
}

int main(void)
{
    char textInput[MAX_LINES][MAX_LINE_LENGTH];

    printf("Enter number of lines (<10): ");
    int textLines = 0;
    scanf("%d", &textLines);

    while(textLines < 1 || textLines > 10)
    {
        printf("Invalid Input.\n");
        printf("Enter number of lines (<10): ");
        scanf("%d", &textLines);
    }
    if(textLines >= 1 && textLines <= 10)
    {
        readText(textInput, textLines);

        int menuActive = 1;

        while(menuActive)
        {

            printf("\nText Analysis\n----\n");
            printf("1-Search By Character\n2-Search By Word\n3-Search By Length\n0-Quit\nPlease enter a selection: ");

            int selection;
            scanf("%d", &selection);

            switch(selection)
            {
                case 0:
                    menuActive = 0;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    printf("Selected 1\n");

                    printf("Enter a character to search: ");
                    char characterSearch;
                    scanf(" %c", &characterSearch);

                    int characterwordCount = searchByCharacter(textInput, textLines, characterSearch);
                    printf("\nNumber of occurence of %c = %d", characterSearch, characterwordCount); 
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("Selected 2\n");

                    printf("Enter a word to search: ");
                    char wordSearch[MAX_LINE_LENGTH];
                    scanf(" %s", wordSearch);

                    int lengthwordCount = searchByWord(textInput, textLines, wordSearch);
                    printf("\nNumber of occurence of %s = %d", wordSearch, lengthwordCount);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf("Selected 3\n");

                    printf("Enter search length: ");
                    int wordLength;
                    scanf(" %d", &wordLength);

                    int wordLengthwordCount = searchByLength(textInput, textLines, wordLength);
                    printf("Number of words with length %d = %d", wordLength, wordLengthwordCount);
                    break;
                default:
                    printf("Invalid Input.\n");
            }
        }
    printf("You Have Quit!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For starters, there should not be an `'s'` after `[^\n]` in `scanf(" %[^\n]s", text[i]);`. The `%[...]` character class is a *format specifier* on its own, just as `%s` is (except unlike `%s` it does not consume leading whitespace -- which you address with the space before it in your *format string*). You should also protect your array bounds with a *width modifier*, e.g. `" %79[^\n]"` to prevent writing beyond the bounds of your array.

Comment: You should also condition your read on the **return** of `scanf`, e.g. `int i = 0; while (i < n && scanf (" %79[^\n]", text[i]) == 1) i++;` You should change the return type of `readText` to `int` and `return i;` so if less than `'n'` strings are entered, you know how many you have. There are many examples of reading strings into a 2D array on this site already. Another short but critical read for you is [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Get your input right, then we will work on parsing.

Comment: Are you aware of the existance of `fgets`?

Comment: Use strncmp instead of strcmp (always).

Comment: What is n++ for?

Comment: @stark I realized that was my error, my brain farted I should have been using j++ wherever I was incrementing n++.

Comment: regarding: `scanf(" %[^\n]s", text[i]);`  This is nonsense.  The '[...]' stops while there is still a '\n' in `stdin`  so there will NEVER be a matching letter 's'.  Strongly suggest removin the 's' from the format string